# Passing Multiple Arguments from Panels into Views ( Drupal)

Tags: drupal

Anyone knows how to pass multiple arguments from Panels into a view in Drupal 6?

**Edit: I know how to pass [one argument](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/04/passing-arguments-from-panel-to-views.html) from Panels into Views, but not multiple arguments.**

Answer (score 2):

In the panels argument field, separate them with a "/"

Something like arg1/arg2/arg3

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is to save your view as a panel pane. Good instructions [here](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/04/passing-arguments-from-panel-to-views.html)

Comment: You know, the ironic thing is that the instructions you provided were written by me myself :). And I wrote it before I asked this question. The instruction was for only a single argument, not multiple arguments because I hadn't figure out how to do multiple arguments, and hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your tutorial you use `site.ru/%` path for panel, so this means that you use the variable `%` as argument. If you write `site.ru/%1/%2,` you can use two argument's variable `%1` and `%2`.